# Framelayout is not allowing add resource image as background

Tags: android, fragment

**Fragment xml file**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxx.boson.com.xxxldigital.fragments.MenuFragment"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:background="@drawable/app1">
   <!-- some simple components -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Without background is running with any problem, but with the background attribute:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital, PID: 11219
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital/sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML
>   file line #1: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
>   Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>                                                                                             at
>   sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital.fragments.MenuFragment.onCreateView(MenuFragment.java:68)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
>   Error inflating class 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
>                                                                                             at
>   sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital.fragments.MenuFragment.onCreateView(MenuFragment.java:68) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
>                                                                                             at
>   sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital.fragments.MenuFragment.onCreateView(MenuFragment.java:68) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412
>   byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 117MB until OOM
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
>                                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
>                                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
>                                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.(View.java:4225)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:589)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:97)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:92)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:88)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
>                                                                                             at
>   sanmiguel.boson.com.sanmigueldigital.fragments.MenuFragment.onCreateView(MenuFragment.java:68) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Any reason you might be getting OOM?

Comment: what kind of file and how large is `@drawable/app1`? that looks to be causing the OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with background image. Its size is too big.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132710412 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 117MB until OOM at dalvik.system

remove this line

```
android:background="@drawable/app1"
```

set id for your layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

on java class file

```
   FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mainLayout.setBackground(getScaledDrawable(R.drawable.app1));
        } else {
            mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getScaledDrawable(R.drawable.app1));
        }

    }
    //scale image here
    private Drawable getScaledDrawable(int resourceID) {

    }
```